# How can I print a variable to a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How can I print the contents of a variable into a text file? For example, I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#My Bash
echo "saisir votre nom" 
read $name
```

I would like to print the contents of `$name` into a text file. How can I do this?

Comment: Read? I'm afraid it's not entirely clear what you're asking here...

Comment: the problem is how can i recover data entered by the user in a text file with bash script how can i do?

Comment: Please give us example. I don't understand what you want. What do you mean by saying "recover"?

Comment: when the user entered data, I want these data will be stored in a text file. Expl: echo (" write your name please") i want that the name while be stored in a text file

Comment: Please, post here the code.

Comment: Ahmed, is your question related to Ubuntu? If it isn't, you'd better ask it on https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: this is the code:  #!/bin/bash
#My Bash

echo "saisir votre nom"
read $name   i want $name will be a text file

Comment: @user300458 simple scripting questions are on topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `echo` or `printf` to print the variable and redirect to a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "saisir votre nom: "  name
printf "%s\n" "$name" > file.txt
```

Alternatively, just print it and run the script redirecting its output:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "saisir votre nom: "  name
printf "%s\n" "$name"
```

Then:

```
myscript.sh > file.txt
```